# Fuel gauge to measure usb OTG consumption

Tags: android, usb, android-source

Can an Android with OTG phone measure power consumed by a device that is connected to it?

I looked into the source code for the fuel gauge in
Code:

```
./apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/fuelgauge
```

, but could not find that it can list usb device consumption.

I have an Xperia Z phone, but it really does not matter which phone, I can switch.

Is there any phone that can show me the usb consumption?

If not, can it be done in software? If I subtract total battery consumption from all the different component that the fuel gauge measure, will I get the USB consumption?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This would depend on the hardware of the given phone, if there is something that allows measuring that.  By default I would assume "no".  If the USB device were a *predictable* load (most are not), you could probably just log how long it is powered and multiply by the load estimate, but I wouldn't expect it to be valid except in special cases.